# Testclass Schedule Batch Error - No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method. Unable to cover

Tags: apex, unit-test, error, schedulebatch

I have Schedulable, Batch class

```
public class Schedule_Batch_CheckUser implements Schedulable ,database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{
public void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
    //I'm using this to avoid error "No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method."
    if(System.Test.isRunningTest()){
        ID jobID = Database.executeBatch(new Schedule_Batch_CheckUser(), 50);
        System.abortJob(jobID);
    }else{
        Database.executeBatch(this, 50);            
    }
        
}

public database.QueryLocator start(database.BatchableContext BC){                               
    String query = 'SELECT Id, POP_User__c FROM User where Name not in (\'Chatter Users\')';
    return database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope){
    //Update User information
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> listPop = [SELECT Id, AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'POP_User'];
    Set<Id> setPopUser= new Set<Id>();
    for(PermissionSetAssignment item : listPop ){
        setPopUser.add(item.AssigneeId);
    }
    
    for(User item : scope){
        if(setPopUser.contains(item.Id)){
            item.Pop_User__c= true;
        }else{
            item.Pop_User__c= false;
        }
    }
    update scope;
}

public void finish(database.BatchableContext BC){       
     
}
```

}

And here is my Test Class

```
@isTest 
public class Schedule_Batch_CheckUser_Test {
private static String CRON_EXP = '0 30 * * * ?';
@testSetup
static void initData(){
    Profile pp = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
    
    User u = new User();
    u.email = 'username2099NQG@pop.com';
    u.CompanyName = 'TEST';
    u.Lastname = 'Last';
    u.Department = 'Customer Success';
    u.Title = 'title';
    u.Alias = 'alias';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u.IsActive = true;
    u.username = 'username2099NQG@pop.com';
    u.ProfileId = pp.Id;
    insert u; 
            
    
    PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id  FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'Popuser' limit 1];
    
    PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment
        (PermissionSetId = ps.Id, AssigneeId = u.Id);
    insert psa;  
}
@isTest
static void test1(){
    
                                         
    System.Test.startTest();                   
    
    Schedule_Batch_CheckUser a = new Schedule_Batch_CheckUser ();
    a.execute(null);        
                
    System.Test.stopTest();                
}
```

}

When I run the test class it return sucessfully but the coverage is just 21% and it only cover first if condition of the first execute method in this

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext SC){   
if(System.Test.isRunningTest()){
    ID jobID = Database.executeBatch(new Schedule_Batch_CheckUser(), 50);
    System.abortJob(jobID);
}
```

only this part is cover. Can you help me why I get this ?

I have follow this to trying to fix it but not working yet.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000936mIAA

Comment: Will this help `https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174732/no-more-than-one-executebatch-can-be-called-from-within-a-test-method`. I already faced this issue in my initial phase in salesforce

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response, however if I add that condition in the query nothing change, the coverage is still 21%. I have try to keep that condition in query and remove isRunningTest checking on the Execute method, but I got the error No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.

Comment: Ok so now you are not facing `No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.` but your coverage is 21%. You need to check which lines are getting covered and check if lines are not getting covered then why is that so. what condition will allow those lines to get covered. 

Also why is this line written `System.abortJob(jobID);`

Comment: So when I try to find the solution for my problem I have seen someone said I should using that condition to run the testclass. If I remove that line `System.abortJob` then the testclass will return failed with the error `No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method`

Comment: After removing `System,abortJob` replace your query with this `'SELECT Id, POP_User__c FROM User where Name not in (\'Chatter Users\')' +(Test.isRunningTest()?' LIMIT 50':'');`

Comment: ah silly me I know how to do it.
It's because the query on batch is limit 200, but my batch size is 50, that's why the batch need to call multiple time, when I change the batch size to 200 then it run like a champ.

Comment: Thanks @NagendraSingh for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `System.abortJob`

Replace your query with `'SELECT Id, POP_User__c FROM User where Name not in (\'Chatter Users\')' +(Test.isRunningTest()?' LIMIT 50':'');` and it should work.

This is because you're querying on a Setup object (one not affected by SeeAllData=false), so you'll need to limit your query. So all your records gets executed within a single batch.